# Java wait/notify

Tags: java, notify

i tried for ages to find out why this is not working but could simply not find an answer.
What i am trying to do, is to have two classes "talking" to eachother.
Basicly i want A to do something and the whait for B(same for B)

```
class ParaTest {
    boolean aCanTalk;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.t();
    }
}

class Test {
    boolean aCanTalk;
    Thread a;
    Thread b;
    void t() {
        aCanTalk = true;
        a = new Thread(new A(this));
        b = new Thread(new B(this));
        a.start();
        b.start();
    }
}

class A implements Runnable {
    Test t;
    A(Test t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(t.aCanTalk) {
            System.out.println("I am A");
            t.aCanTalk = false;
            synchronized(this) {
                notifyAll();
            }
            try {
                synchronized(t.b) {
                    t.b.wait();
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {};
        }
    }
}

class B implements Runnable {
    Test t;
    B(Test t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(!t.aCanTalk) {
            System.out.println("I am B");
            t.aCanTalk = true;
            synchronized(this) {
                notify();
            }           
            try {
                synchronized(t.a) {
                    t.a.wait();
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {};
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say that it is not working, what is it doing?

Comment: it prints "I am A" and stops

Comment: I'm sure someone is already writing a long Comprehensive answer. The issue here are that (1) you have a data race on t.aCanTalk, which is a non-volatile variable, and (2) A and B are not synchronized relative to each other, because they synchronize on two different locks. synchronized only works if two threads synchronize on the same object. Try synchronized(t) (you'll have to mark t as final, which doesn't seem to be a problem in your case)

Comment: @ortusolis So you want A to wait for B until B prints 'I am B', and the same for B (wait for A until A prints 'I am A'), is this correct?

Comment: @ortusolis Tell me exactly what `B.run` will do if `t.aCanTalk` is false when it starts.

Comment: @Magnamag yes. This is a small example but i need it for a bigger programm. I think i have bit of a plroblem understanding how exactly wait and notify work

Comment: If you can tell what `while(false)` does you are halfway to solving the problems yourself.

Comment: @ortusolis It is not quite clear if you want your program to output "I am A"  "I am B" and then finish, or "I am A" "I am B" "I am A" "I am B" ...  Anyway there are now answers to both cases, but you might want to clarify your question.

Comment: Havent looked at all of your code, but make sure you move all t interactions like t.aCanTalk = false inside the synchronized blocks. Also you need to synchronize on `t` not `this`.

Answer (score 1):

There are other problems (see below) with your code, but the one you're stumbling on is that since the condition is checked before getting to the wait, as in `B`:

```
  public void run() {
    while(!t.aCanTalk) {
    ....
    }
  }
```

if `t.aCanTalk` is true, the run method will simply return, and the thread die.

(My initial misreading of your code illustrates the following :-) )

That said, you should really restructure the code as it is less error prone if you make a proper monitor with more "packaged" methods, for instance a simple rendez-vous example:

```
class Test {
    private boolean aCanTalk = true;

    public synchronized waitA() {
        while(!aCanTalk) {
            wait();
        }
    }

    public synchronized signalB() {
        aCanTalk = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized waitB() {
        while(aCanTalk) {
            wait();
        }
    }

    public synchronized signalA() {
        aCanTalk = true;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

and use that in your threads, like for instance 
in A:

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        t.waitA();
        System.out.println("I am A");
        t.signalB();
    }
}
```

and B:

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        t.waitB();
        System.out.println("I am B");
        t.signalA();
    }
}
```

(`InterruptedException` ignored for brevity, it should be caught or thrown somewhere as you did in your code)

Comment: Actually the OP's use of wait and notify works correctly. Read it again. `a` waits on `b` and notifies itself (`a`), `b` waits on `a` and notifies itself (`b`). It's not good but it's not inherently a problem either.

Comment: @SRobertz Just to add to your answer, here there's no need to make `aCanTalk` volatile, since you're accesing it from within `synchronized` methods, and this makes `aCanTalk` changes immediately visible to all threads.

Comment: @Radiodef yes, I just saw that. So the problem is that there is a race condition in the thread startup: if the condition in the while loop is false, the thread will simply exit and not reach its wait. Will edit

Comment: @Magnamag it is not volatile, but i edited it to be private just to clarify that it should only be used in the monitor operations.

Comment: @SRobertz Sure, it wasn't a correction to your answer, but a clarification, since someone else had commented somewhere about making `aCanTalk` volatile.

Answer (score 1):

1. synchronizing two threads should be made by using the *same* lock. Using different objects to lock on, you're unnecessarily complicating the situation.
2. Any call to `wait`, `notify` or `notifyAll` should be surrounded by
   try/catch clause (for `IllegalMonitorStateException` and
   `InterruptedException`).
3. If you want a thread to wait for another thread after it finished running, you should use [`join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html).
4. In your case, both threads should synchronize on `Boolean aCanTalk;` (note the capital `B`!).
5. Any `wait()` should be checked in a `while` loop that checks the
   change of state of the object we're synchronizing on.
6. A better practice is to not use `notify()`, but use only `notifyAll()` (though it doesn't matter in this particular case cause there are only two threads).
7. Java has evolved since `wait` and `notify` were introduced, and today, for most purposes, you don't have to use any of them.

The following implementation, doesn't use `wait` or `notify` and still achieves the same synchronization of execution:

```
class ParaTest {
    volatile boolean aCanTalk;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.t();
    }
}

class Test {
    volatile Boolean aCanTalk;
    Thread a;
    Thread b;
    void t() {
        aCanTalk = true;
        a = new Thread(new A(this));
        b = new Thread(new B(this));
        a.start();
        b.start();
        try {
            a.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class A implements Runnable {
    Test t;
    A(Test t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I am A");
        synchronized(t.aCanTalk) {
            System.out.println("in synchronized (A)");
            t.aCanTalk = false;
        }
        System.out.println("finished (A)");
    }

}

class B implements Runnable {
    Test t;
    B(Test t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I am B");
        synchronized(t.aCanTalk) {
            System.out.println("in synchronized (B)");
            t.aCanTalk = true;
        }
        System.out.println("finished (B)");

    }

}
```

Comment: The second point is not correct: you *have to* synchronize on the object you want to `wait` on. And waiting releases the lock.

Answer (score -1):

If you are wanting to wait for a thread to finish, try "join". There is a good example in the java documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html

So, in your case if you want to wait for A to finish before calling start on B.

```
a.start();
a.join();
b.start();
```

At least, this is what I think you are asking (Your question seems a bit unclear).

Comment: I basicly tried to get A to do somethig, the call B, the get B to do something and call A abd so on. Sry, if the question was a bit unclear